# How to get system.d service startup dependencies for network.target to behave like network-online.target?

Tags: systemd, services, startup

I am operating a CentOS8 (8.1.1911) minimal install for the purposes of running a web server.

Some services in `/etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/` such as

- `httpd.service`
- `mariadb.service`
- `named.service`
- `squid.service`
- `sshd.service`
- `postfix.service`

have only `After=network.target` and not `network-online.target`.

This is a problem because on system boot up these services are starting before the network is ready and failing to bind to any listening ports. Luckily a couple like `sshd` keep retrying to bind and once the network is online they succeed. You can see in `/var/log/messages` failed to bind attempts before eventually succeeding. However not all services will retry and after the first fail stay dead.

I know one solution is to add custom parameters for `Wants`/`After` on each service using `systemctl`, i.e. run

```
systemctl edit httpd
```

and add

```
[Unit]
Wants=network-online.target
After=network-online.target
```

This works, services will now wait for the network to be online and successfully binds and starts on reboot.

**Now for my question.**

I do not want to manually edit each service to add `network-online.target` as this creates a maintenance headache and the possibility of forgetting this step on new services installed in the future. What I want is a way to set a policy or make a change system wide, that any service with a `Wants`/`After` for `network.target` will behave as if it is waiting for `network-online.target`.

- Will this create a problem since `NetworkManager` also waits for `network.target`? Could `NetworkManager` be changed to wait on something else?
- Any other services that might break if all `network.target` waited for `network-online.target`?
- Any other creative solutions?